# C-preprocessor #define SQR(x) ( x * x )

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I think I'm going crazy. I'm learning C-preprocessor and I can't figure this problem out, I defined SQR(x) (X*X) purposely without brackets

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #define SQR(x) (x * x)
 int main()
 {
    int counter; /* counter for loop */
    for(counter = 0; counter < 5; ++counter) 
    {
        printf("x %d, x squared %d\n",counter+1, SQR(counter+1))
    }
    return (0);
 }
```

In one moment in loop counter = 3. Then it should be 3 + 1 * 3 + 1 and that is equal to 7, but the output says 5.
Here is output of the code above:

```
x 1, x squared 1
x 2, x squared 3
x 3, x squared 5
x 4, x squared 7
x 5, x squared 9

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.020 s
Press any key to continue.
```

I'm clearly missing something but I can't figure it out.

Comment: You are correct it is 7. You are printing counter with one added so your answers are mismatched by one.

Comment: When you print `x 3`, `counter` is `2`.

Comment: Yea but print's clearly says: "x 3, x squared 5"
so im using compare+1 to print and then compare +1 to calc. 
Same value

Comment: yea i can see it now, thank you guys for your time

Comment: Why did you purposely not enclose the arguments in parentheses? What on earth could be your reason for doing something you know to be a mistake?

Comment: I was reading a book, and there was this example that show that you need to use brackets or something like this will happen, but then i overthinked this example...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When counter=3, it prints as *4* because you print `counter+1`. Use:

```
printf("x %d, x squared %d\n",counter, SQR(counter+1));
```

to see what the *actual* value of counter is.

Comment: Yeap,stupid me thank you...

Comment: @CareyGregory OP stated he knows about this issue and he "defined SQR(x) (X*X) purposely without brackets"

Comment: Hmm... you're right; I overlooked that. What the heck?

Comment: @CareyGregory dont ask ;)

Comment: Or: `printf("x == %d; (x + 1) wrongly squared == %d\n", counter, SQR(counter + 1));`.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the most obvious error pointed out in Ignaus' answer, you have a second, more insidious and more dangerous error here. Do the substitution that the preprocessor will do on `SQR`:

```
SQR(counter+1)
```

becomes:

```
counter+1 * counter+1
```

which will be executed as if it were written like this:

```
counter + (1 * counter) + 1
```

That is obviously incorrect and not what you intended. With macros, you should **always** enclose the arguments in parentheses. So your macro should look like this:

```
#define SQR(x) ((x) * (x))
```

Now do the substitution again and you get:

```
((counter+1) * (counter+1))
```

which is correct. Make it a habit to **always** include macro arguments in parentheses to avoid these sorts of errors.

Comment: This is a good point, but OP says he knows about this and did it on purpose

Comment: Reading a book, and there was this example that show that you need to use parantheses or something like this will happen, but then i overthinked this example...

Comment: @honeyPot You mean parentheses `()` not brackets `{}`. Right?

Comment: yea, english is not my main, so i'm calling brackets everything :D, thank you for correcting me